# Java Regex: Extracting a Version Number

Tags: java, regex, numbers, version, extract

I have a program that stores the version number in a text file on the file system. I import the file within java and I am wanting to extract the version number. I'm not very good with regex so I am hoping someone can help.

The text file looks like such:

```
0=2.2.5 BUILD (tons of other junk here)
```

I am wanting to extract `2.2.5`. Nothing else. Can someone help me with the regex for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the structure, you don't need a regex:

```
    String line = "0=2.2.5 BUILD (tons of other junk here)";
    String versionNumber = line.split(" ", 2)[0].substring(2);
```

Comment: I would look for the index of the equals sign and the space, and do a substring. I think that would be more robust.

Comment: I tried this out since it looked a lot simpler than using a regex. It worked wonderfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should do the trick:

```
(?<==)\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?=\s*BUILD)
```

Trying it out:

```
String s = "0=2.2.5 BUILD (tons of other junk here)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<==)\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?=\\s*BUILD)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

```
2.2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are really looking for a regex, though there are definitely many ways to do this.

```
String line = "0=2.2.5 BUILD (tons of other junk here)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^\\d+=((\\d|\\.)+)").matcher(line);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Output:

```
2.2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one of them

```
String data = "0=2.2.5 BUILD (tons of other junk here)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+=(\\d+([.]\\d+)+) BUILD").matcher(data);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

If you are sure that `data` contains version number then you can also

```
System.out.println(data.substring(data.indexOf('=')+1,data.indexOf(' ')));
```